# Android SQLite что указать в Selection

Tags: android, sqlite

Делаю поиск в приложении, в массиве SelectionArgs названия нужных книг, что нужно указать в selection, чтобы вывести необходимые книги?

```
String or = " OR ?";
String selection = "B_NAME = ?";
for (int i = 0; i< selectionArgs.length; i++){
    selection += or;
}
Cursor c = myDbHelper.query1("BOOK_TABLE_ALL", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Делаю так, выводит только первый элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неверный запрос у вас.

Правильно так:

```
select * from BOOK_TABLE_ALL where B_NAME in (?,?,?)
```

или

```
select * from BOOK_TABLE_ALL where B_NAME=? or B_NAME=? or B_NAME=?
```

Для первого варианта будет как-то так:

```
StringBuilder selection = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < selectionArgs.length; i++){
    if(selection.length()>0)
        selection.append(",");
    selection.append("?");
}
selection.insert(0, "B_NAME in (");
selection.append(")");

dbHelper.query(..., selection.toString(), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить часть:

```
String or = " OR ?";
String selection = "B_NAME = ?";
for (int i = 0; i< selectionArgs.length; i++){
selection += or;
}
```

на:

```
String or = " OR ";
String template = "B_NAME=?";
String selection = "B_NAME=?";
for (int i = 0; i< selectionArgs.length - 1; i++){
selection += or + template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По моему должно работать с условием `OR`, при условии что аргументов > 0

```
StringBuilder selection = new StringBuilder();

selection.append("SELECT * FROM BOOK_TABLE_ALL WHERE ");
String b_name = " B_NAME = ? ";
String or = " OR ";
if(selectionArgs.length > 1){// аргументов > 1
    for (int i = 0; i< selectionArgs.length - 1; i++){
          selection.append(b_name).append(or);        
                       }                 
          }
    selection.append(b_name);//аргумент только 1 или > 1

Cursor c = myDbHelper.rawQuery(selection.toString(), selectionArgs);
```